# Video encoded with ffmpeg not playing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying just about every single permutation of options on ffmpeg to try to get a transcoded video to display on Chrome - OSX 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) - so far nothing has worked.

The settings I am currently using look like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.4.3/bin/ffmpeg -i source.m4v -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -preset slower -crf 23 -vf scale=640:360 target.mp4
```

but I've tried various options from various other answers with no success.

The video-js demo video works fine, so it must be possible somehow.  Here's a dump of the encoded video:

```
*** General Parameters ***
- Name:  test-1 (2).mp4 
- Container:  MP4 - QuickTime 
- Size:  3.45 MB 
- Duration:  32s 299ms 
- Bitrate:  856 Kbps 

*** Video Track Parameters ***
- Format:  H.264/MPEG-4 AVC 
- Bitrate:  Max.: --- / Average: 721 Kbps / Min.: --- 
- Frame rate (fps):  Max.: --- / Average: 30.000 / Min.: --- 
- Encoding profile:  Baseline@L3.0 
- Image size:  640*360 
- Pixel Aspect Ratio:  Undefined 
- Display Aspect Ratio:  16:9 
- Interlacing:  Progressive 

*** First Audio Track Parameters ***
- Format:  AAC - MPEG-4 audio 
- Bitrate:  128 Kbps 
- Resolution:  Undefined 
- Rate:  44.1 KHz 
- Channel(s):  2 (stereo) 
- Position:  Front: L R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the metadata is in the wrong place.  Adding `-movflags +faststart` to the ffmpeg parameter list makes it start working.